# Which of these graphics card is the best?

Tags: graphics-card

**AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512MB**

or

**AMD Radeon HD R7 M265 with dedicated memory of 2GB DDR3**

I can not quite understand AMD products nomenclature ....

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say that the newer one, with four times the amount of VRAM as the other, is going to work a lot better. I am, of course, talking about the Radeon HD R7. I'm not sure why there's a competition for you between the two, so explaining that would help.

Comment: hi, thanks! actually i don't know much about these stuff.. i didn't knew which one was newer and 6770 is a bigger number than 265 so i thought it could be better... hahaha

Comment: (i have 2 computers here at home and i have to decide which one to give it away, keeping the best one)